# Fastest way to store 3D numpy array in a loop

Tags: python, list, numpy, performance, matlab

I need to store a numpy array of shape (2000,720,1280) which is created in every loop. My code looks like:

```
    U_list = []   
      
    for N_f in range(N): 
             U = somefunction(N_f)
             U_list.append(U)
             del U
```

So I delete the matrix U in every loop because my RAM get full.

Is this a good method to store the matrix U or would you recommend another solution? I compare the code to matlab and matlab need the half time to compute. I think the storage of U in a list could be the reason.

Comment: To clarify: your `U` arrays are each 2000x720x1280? What's `N`? One option may be to preallocate a single large NumPy array and refactor `somefunction` to write directly to a slice of that array, rather than appending in a loop.

Comment: N is in the order of 5. I should mention that I only need the first 10 matrices of U, i.e. U[:10,:,:]. So, I store a matrix of size 10x720x1280 in every loop. But this is still very slow.

Comment: Computing 2000x720x1280 results is going to be very expensive; why do you compute so much data if you only need the first 10 elements of U? Is there maybe a cleverer way to write `somefunction` so it just computes the data you're interested in?

Comment: I already have done this. The storage of data is still very slow.

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a bit more code. Just appending to a list in Python is very fast, especially if that list is only going to have ~N=5 elements in it. The elements in the list will just be references to the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using this method will tell you if you are able to store the total U arrays right out the gate. If N is so large that you can't make the results numpy array, you'll have to get creative. Maybe save every 20 into a pickle file or something.

```
import numpy as np

N = 20
shape = (2000, 720, 1280)
#Make sure to match the dtype returned by somefunction
results = np.zeros((N, *shape)) 
for N_f in range(N):
    results[N_f] = somefunction(N_f)
```